# How does ml.feature.StringIndexer and IndexToString work?

Tags: apache-spark, feature-extraction

from the official doc, they don't talk to each other, and yet they can work together.

```
df = sqlCtx.createDataFrame([(0, "a",'s', ['dance']), (1, "b",'b', ['sing']), (2, "c",'a', ['dance','sing']), (3, "a",'x', []), (4, "a",'xx',['football']), (5, "c",'w', ['dance'])],["id", "rand_one",'rand_two', 'hobbies'])
indexer_one = StringIndexer(inputCol='rand_one', outputCol='one')
indexer_two = StringIndexer(inputCol='rand_two', outputCol='two')
transformed_one = indexer_one.fit(df).transform(df)
transformed_two = indexer_two.fit(transformed_one).transform(transformed_one)
get_back_one = IndexToString(inputCol='one', outputCol='origin_one')
get_back_two = IndexToString(inputCol='two', outputCol='origin_two')
magic_back = get_back_two.transform(transformed_two)
```

how did this happen? for only indexer_one have the information of mapping and get_back_one just have it with anything value assign

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#indextostring):

> "...we are able to retrieve our original labels (they will be inferred
>   from the columns’ metadata)."

Thus the mapping does persist, which is why if we create a copy of the column `transformed_two['two']`:

```
transformed_two = transformed_two.withColumn('two_test', transformed_two['two'].cast('double'))
```

And then try to implement `IndexToString`:

```
get_back_two = IndexToString(inputCol='two_test', outputCol='origin_two')
magic_back = get_back_two.transform(transformed_two)
```

We get the following error:

> Java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   org.apache.spark.ml.attribute.UnresolvedAttribute$ cannot be cast to
>   org.apache.spark.ml.attribute.NominalAttribute